# Algebra - Why is my answer wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question: A student's grade in a course is the average of 4 test grades and a final exam that is worth twice as much. Suppose a student has test grades of 91, 82, 83, and 92. Write an equation to model this situation where x is the student's grade on the final exam and y is the student's average for the course.Then find the score they will need to receive on their final exam if they want to have a grade of 90 for the course.

My equation:

$G (grade) = \frac{2}{3} x + \frac{1}{3} y$

$y = (91 + 82 + 83 +92)/4 = 87$

$90 = \frac{2}{3} x + \frac{1}{3}87$

$90 = \frac{2}{3} x + 29$, implies  $61 = \frac{2}{3} x$ which further implies $x = 61 \times \frac{3}{2}$.

My answer is $x = 91.5$

But the actual answer is 96.

Confused :/

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the question. Assume the final exam is worth twice as much as 1 of the test grades (not twice as much as all of the test grades combined), and you will obtain the answer 96.

Comment: @Tyson  91.5 looks perfectly reasonable given the wording though.

Comment: The first sentence of the question is ambiguous.  Had I written it, I would have said "A student's grade in a course is the average of four test grades and a final exam that is worth as much as two tests."

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would solve it.

We want the weighted average of all the test grades for the overall grade:
$$G_{overall}=\frac{1*G_1+1*G_2+1*G_3+1*G_4+2*G_{final}}{1+1+1+1+2}$$
$$G_{overall}=\frac{G_1+G_2+G_3+G_4+2*G_{final}}{6}$$

Using the requested symbols, substitute: $y=G_{overall},x=G_{final}$. We know what the overall grade the student wants to get is, so we just plug that in. We know what the four grades are for the four tests, so we plug that in as well.
$$y=\frac{91+82+83+92+2*x}{6}=90$$
Now we can solve for $x$.
$$(91+82+83+92+2*x)=6*90=540 \rightarrow 2*x=540-91-82-83-92=192$$
Notice how the *weighted* score has to be $192$. This is okay, since the weight of the final is twice anything else, so we divide the weighted score by $2$ to get the actual numerical grade.
$$x=96$$

Comment: A student's grade in a course is the average of 4 test grades (that's one number) and a final exam that is worth twice as much (that's a second number). Just because someone says an answer is 96 does not mean you change the question?

Comment: It looks like you meant $x = G_{\text{final}}$ and $y = G_{\text{overall}}$.

Comment: Good catch, fixed it! :)